# group by VS window function

Tags: mysql

Can anyone please help me to understand the difference between the codes below regarding LEETCODE 1076.
Enquiry is 'Write an SQL query that reports all the projects that have the most employees.'

1.

```sql
SELECT T1.PROJECT_ID 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
        P.PROJECT_ID,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (partition by PROJECT_ID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS CRANK
        FROM PROJECT AS P 
      
    )   AS T1
WHERE T1.CRANK = 1;
```

2. 

```sql
SELECT T1.PROJECT_ID 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
        P.PROJECT_ID,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS CRANK
        FROM PROJECT AS P 
      group by PROJECT_ID
    )   AS T1
WHERE T1.CRANK = 1
```

Comment: First query is incorrect. It will fail if `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is enabled and will return indefinite output otherwise. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a27083b15dac34e9b754af7ccad93b58

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Could you please help to explain if the below one will make and difference comparing to the second one.                                     
      SELECT T1.PROJECT_ID 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
        P.PROJECT_ID,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER ( partition by P.PROJECT_ID, ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS CRANK
        FROM PROJECT AS P 
      group by PROJECT_ID
    )   AS T1
WHERE T1.CRANK = 1

Comment: Execute the subquery only, and add COUNT(*) to the output list. You'll see...